# Does there exist a function $f(n)$ that $f(n^2) = O(f(n))$

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics

Does there exist a function $f(n)$ that $f(n^2) = O(f(n))$

In other words I need to show that there exists $,\exists n_0 ,c \gt 0 , \forall n \gt n_0$ that will makes this true:

$$f(n^2) \le c \cdot f(n)$$

I thought about taking $\frac{1}{n}$, Because then:

$\cfrac{1}{n^2} \le c \cfrac{1}{n} \rightarrow \cfrac{1}{n} \le c \rightarrow 1 \le c\cdot n$ Which is true, for example $c = 1, n = 2$

Comment: You can try $f=1$.

Comment: ... Yes, your example is correct. Were you just asking for verification?

Comment: @heptagon Oh that makes sense, I thought in the beginning that the function I must provide must include $n$ in it because of "$f(n)$". Thanks sir

Comment: @DustanLevenstein This is new to me, so I'm trying to see if I undersstand the principles right. Thanks btw.

Comment: For an unbounded $f$, try $f(n)=\log(n)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I got to $log(n) \le c$ what can I conclude from that?

Comment: Try again. $\log(n^2)=?$ @IlanAizelmanWS

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $2\cdot log(n)$. Thanks Thomas! Btw, the question stated that the function should be unbounded.

Comment: Next exercise: Create an unbounded function that fits the constraint with $c=1$. (Don't take this challenge too seriously - I'm kind of trolling. It is doable though.)